# MeshRestClient hanging

Tags: java, mesh, gentics-mesh

I'n mew with Gentics Mesh. I'm trying the MeshRestClient in Java on the docker demo.

My code is very simple: just a login and a webroot call. My program is just a command line project. After the call my program don't resume and seems hanging.

I've commented the webroot call so my program is just a login but same behavior... What's wrong?

My pom.xml

```
   <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>mesh-rest-client</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.gentics.mesh</groupId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.gentics.com</id>
        <name>Gentics Maven Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.gentics.com/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And my program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MeshRestClient client = MeshRestClient.create("localhost", 8090, false);
    System.out.println(MeshRestClient.getPlainVersion());
    client.setLogin("admin", "admin");
    client.login().blockingGet();
```

System.out.println("After login...");
}

Thanks for your help

Comment: After login is dispalyed so login is success but after that noop, program is not exiting

Comment: Program is not really hanging but seems waiting and terminates after a long time.